# How to install Rigs Of Rods on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

How do I install Rigs of Rods on Ubuntu 14.04? I do not want to use wine, but when trying to install from the PPA, it said the package was not found.

Comment: Yeah, same error here,but an alternative is to compile the Game, here is how: [Compile Rigs of Rod in Linux](https://github.com/RigsOfRods/rigs-of-rods/wiki/Compile-(Linux))

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

Add ppa repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:aapo-rantalainen/rigsofrods
```

Update package list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install rigsofrods package:

```
 sudo apt-get install rigsofrods
```

Comment: I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about what this command does. A plain command or command sequence is rarely considered an answer. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: I get this error

Comment: E: Unable to locate package rigsofrods